# Is there a client-side IDE for textareas on webpages?

Tags: ide, textarea, inline

Much of my work involves a web-based CMS I cannot modify. That means lots of textareas, and none of the IDE features I love, such as tab functionality, syntax highlighting, etc.

Are there any browser modifications, or bookmarklets, or anything that would allow a client side inline override of textareas, allowing IDE like features (even as basic as simply allowing use of the tab key instead of alt+009) in a webpage's textarea field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are. For example: [Web Wiz Rich Text Editor](http://www.webwiz.co.uk/webwizrichtexteditor/), the first one I found when Googling "browser text editor". :) It appears to be free to use, with paid premium versions.

I'm sure there are others!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think putting 'textarea' in my google searches is what muddied up the results. That does appear to be way closer towards what I'm looking for, but it does seem more oriented towards rich text / wysiwyg editing, and I'm aiming more for code-related. I need to make sure it doesn't add lots of extra markup since I'm often editing proprietary tags within html code.